# MVC Captcha and session are different

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, session, captcha

I want to use captcha validation for my login page in LoginController I wrote

```
[HttpGet]
        [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "None")] // This is for output cache false
        public FileResult GetCaptchaImage()
        {
            CaptchaRandomImage CI = new CaptchaRandomImage();
            this.Session["CaptchaImageText"] = CI.GetRandomString(5); // here 5 means I want to get 5 char long captcha
            //CI.GenerateImage(this.Session["CaptchaImageText"].ToString(), 300, 75);
            // Or We can use another one for get custom color Captcha Image 
            CI.GenerateImage(this.Session["CaptchaImageText"].ToString(), 300, 75, Color.DarkGray, Color.White);
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            CI.Image.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return new FileStreamResult(stream, "image/png");
        }
```

in html part I wrote

```
 <span class="input-group-addon"style="width: 20%; background: transparent;border: none"><img src="@Url.Action("GetCaptchaImage","Login")" style="width:80px; height: 45px;margin-left: -12px" /></span>
```

Problem is that Session and image are not equal because when login page loads, firstly captcha works then page works, so always session stores the previous images code. How can I solve this problem?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly wiev starts ,then anothers starts, Your code is right but u should do it in controller, not in view, u should add one parameter more to your post action that is authcode, then in controller u can check and do.